# Nested object type definition

Tags: typescript

I have a nested object and I would like to write a type definition for it. Here is the object:

```js
const colors = {
  grayscale: {
    black: '#141414',
    darkGray: '#303030',
    white: '#F0F0F0',
  },
  green1: '#1DB954',
  green2: '#1ED760',
}
```

And here is how I tried to write the type definition:

```js
interface ObjectOf<V> {
  [_: string]: V
}

type ColorObject = ObjectOf<string> | string
type Colors = ObjectOf<ColorObject>

const colors: Colors = {
  ... (same object as above)
}
```

I used `ObjectOf<V>` to have an object that can have any key that's a string, but only values of type `V`. This seems to work for objects that aren't nested.

When I try to use this object like so: `colors.grayscale.black`, the typescript compiler gives me this error:

```
Property 'black' does not exist on type 'ColorObject'.
  Property 'black' does not exist on type 'string'.  TS2339

  > 82 |     backgroundColor: colors.grayscale.black,
       |                                       ^
```

It seems like typescript is ignoring the fact that a `ColorObject` can be an `ObjectOf<>`, meaning any string should be a valid key. Instead it thinks it can only be a string, so getting the `black` key of the `grayscale` object fails. Why is this, and/or how can I fix the type definition so I can use my colors object as it is?

Comment: It's not ignoring that it *can* be an `ObjectOf<string>`.  It's worried that it *might* be a `string`, and in that case it will not have a property named `black`.  You're only allowed to access properties of a union that exist in all members of the union.  Or you have to eliminate members of the union by testing, such as  `if (typeof colors.grayscale === "string") throw new Error();` and then accessing `colors.grayscale.black`.  Why annotate `colors` as `Colors` at all?  It's a fairly wide type that intentionally forgets the structure of `colors`.  What's your use case?

Comment: I see, that makes sense. My use case is using the colors object and another similar object for styles in React components. Typescript was giving me errors when I used strings like "row" for properties that can only accept certain strings like flexDirection, even though "row" is one of those valid values. I thought I would specify the types of all these objects to avoid this, but I guess that's not the best solution.

Comment: I got rid of the type definition for colors and I might post a different question on the actual problem I'm having (right now I'm using a type cast to appease the compiler but idk if that's the best solution). Thanks for the guidance!

Comment: What about the following:
```ts
const colors = {
  grayscale: {
    black: '#141414',
    darkGray: '#303030',
    white: '#F0F0F0',
  },
  green1: '#1DB954',
  green2: '#1ED760',
} as const

type Colors = typeof colors
```

I tend to use this where a have some concrete structure and I want to build a strong contract from it. I can export only the type and the source of truth over the app will be the `colors` object. When you add remove something in it the type updates automatically.
There are few drawbacks, but still useful I believe.

Comment: @rusev Thank you, this is exactly what I need! Would you like to submit this as an answer so I can accept it? If not, I will post it as my own answer just so other people can see it.

Comment: @NoamBendelac Sure! I'm glad that it helps. And sorry for the bad formatting in the previous comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about the following:

```
const colors = { 
  grayscale: { 
    black: '#141414', 
    darkGray: '#303030', 
    white: '#F0F0F0', 
  }, 
  green1: '#1DB954', 
  green2: '#1ED760', 
} as const 

type Colors = typeof colors
```

I tend to use this where I have some concrete structure and I want to build a strong contract from it. I can export only the type and the source of truth over the app will be the colors object. When you add remove something in it the type updates automatically. There are few drawbacks, but still useful I believe.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I don't need `type Colors = typeof colors` because I export `colors` and typescript is aware of its type throughout the project